# Using the 'zoo package' in R to sum data for a month

Tags: r, zoo

I've got some data in the following format in the R studio workspace:

```
Date                  Value
2013-10-01 0:05:00    4.34
2013-10-01 0:10:00    3.04
2013-10-01 0:15:00    4.56
2013-10-01 0:20:00    5.00
......
......
......
......
2013-10-02 23:55:00   4.08
```

How will be able to get the data on an hourly basis for each day. Something like this:

```
Date                   Value
2013-10-01 1:00:00    (what ever the sum of the value 5 minute interval for that hour is)
2013-10-01 2:00:00     "
.....
.....
.....
2013-10-02 24:00:00    "
```

Thanks!

Comment: How about sharing some actually reproducible sample data and show us what you've tried first.

Comment: When asking questions on SO, specifying what package you want to use (`zoo` in your case) is rarely of any use, since there might be better options you don't know about. Concentrate on providing data, example code and what you want to achive.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `rollapplyr`.

```
rollapplyr(yourdataframe, width=12, FUN=sum, by=12)
```